# How do I set a unique constraint for a transformed data in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a model with fields `name` (string) and `created_at` (datetime) and I want a row with its name to be unique only within the hour it was created. That's how I tried:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'created_at__hour')
```

I get the error:

```
(models.E012) 'unique_together' refers to the nonexistent field 'created_at__hour'.
```

What is the correct way to reach what I need?

As the database I have PostgreSQL v12.

Comment: use module datetime or use timezone from django.utils.

Comment: You can try to build something like that with a `UniqueConstraint`, see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint

Comment: @YvesHary And how exactly do I use it in my case?

Comment: I have to be honest: I never tried it. It seems to me, that you can set up a condition, which could match with your needs of `created_at__hour`.

Comment: Some research later: there is a method `model.validate_unique()` you can overwrite to ensure uniqueness (but not at database level). See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique